# Are the parent's font faces accessible in an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, cross-domain, font-face

Let's say a page declares a `font-face` in the stylesheets and contains an iframe pointing to a page on another domain. Will the page in an iframe be able to use the `font-face` from the parent page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't. The iframe page doesn't inherit any CSS from the parent page.

You will need to include the style sheet for the font in the iframe page also.

Comment: What about the other way around? 

I have a requirement to preview dynamic custom fonts, and they are working locally, but not in the real environment (within an iframe).
Is the fact that the parent document has not the font loaded a possible cause of the issue?